# Prefix a selector both as parent and intersection

Tags: css, sass, less, stylus

I know the title is not very descriptive, so I'm going to show an example of the behaviour I need:

**Input**

```
@mixin superScopeMixin {
  /* ... */
}

.one {
  superScopeMixin {
    .two {
      .three {
        /* ... */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```css
.one.two .three,
.one .two .three {
  /* ... */
}
```

I want a selector to be prefixed both "with a space" and "without a space". Is this possible? I can use Less, Sass, or Stylus.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not add the `&` selector to `.two` as well...eg. `&.two, .two { .three { } }`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can setup your mixin like this:

```
@mixin superScopeMixin {
  &.two, .two {
    color: #fff;
    .three {
      color: purple;
    }
  }
}

.one {
  color: gray;
  @include superScopeMixin
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.one {
  color: gray;
}
.one.two, .one .two {
  color: #fff;
}
.one.two .three, .one .two .three {
  color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Although this is indeed the effect I’m trying to achieve, I want to be able to **pass a block to the mixin**, and have the contents of that block be prefixed.

Comment: Update your question to be more clear. Give an example of a `block` that you want to pass. Right now, it's a bit too vague.